# How to include paired data design into a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, paired-data

I have an experimental design with:
20 locations,
2 different treatments by location,
10 samples of response variable "y" by treatment.

It is a nested design but my main question is: Are there differences between treatments? I am wondering if the following mixed model is appropriate to answer my question or I should run a paired test since I have paired treatments in each location.
I did it with R.

```
library(lme4)
model1 <- lmer(y~Treatment+(1|Location),data=data)
```

In case this was a valid way to approach it, should I include the slope as a random effect? (i.e. `(1+Treatment|Location)`)?

Comment: Is treatment a between-pair or within-pair factor? If the latter, transpose to a wide dataset and use `lmer(y.trt1 ~ offset(y.trt0) + (1|Location), data=data)` to perform inference on the treatment differences inspect the intercept.

Comment: Yes, you should include slope as a random effect. Otherwise you might not have valid tests (if you e.g. plan to get p-values from lmerTest, it won't be able to estimate degrees of freedom correctly).

Comment: Thank you AdamO and amoeba. I am not sure. I think it is a within-pair factor, because each location has a control plot and a treatment plot. The same treatment accross the 20 locations.

Comment: Yes, it's within. @AdamO There are 10 samples by treatment, so I am not sure how your suggested model would work in this case.

Comment: @AdamO, I did what you suggested. The problem is that in some locations I only have 4 samples in treatment plot and 4 in control plot and I feel that the statistical power diminishes a lot. I think that my previous model would work as a "paired" model since I am comparing Treatment vs Control, and controlling for the location by including it as a random factor. What do you think about it? Any other suggestion? Thank you

Comment: @amoeba, my interest is to model the general slope between treatments (generalize if there is a significant slope between treatments across locations). If I included it as a random factor that would be wrong.

Comment: No it would not. `y ~ Treatment + (Treatment | Location)` is a perfectly fine model.

Comment: @amoeba The OP mentions paired data and nowhere in the discussion is anything addressing the paired structure. The least squares regression analogue for a paired t-test is to take one paired observation as the outcome and the other paired observation as a covariate with a slope of one. Further regression coefficients in the model model within-pair differences or interactions with unadjusted within-pair predictors. Rather than modeling the cluster-pair effects with a random or fixed effect, it is conditioned on. I don't know much more about the OP's actual design.

Comment: @AdamO `lmer(y ~ condition + (1|subject))` is equivalent to paired t-test. But what I meant is that in this case for each "subject" there are multiple measurements in each of the two "conditions". So I don't understand how one can "take one paired observation as the outcome and the other paired observation as a covariate with a slope of one" -- there are *several* observations in condition A and *several* observations in condition B for each subject.

Comment: @amoeba I disagree that the random intercepts model is equivalent to a paired t-test. Maybe it's worth exploring in a separate question? The Venebles and Ripley book has a good example of pre/post weight gain data that demonstrates handling paired data in this fashion, and performing the ANCOVA in R. The OP said these data were paired, if they are not paired then by no means is a paired analysis appropriate.

Comment: @AdamO Terminology question: would you call data with 20 subjects, each subject measured in condition A and B, 10 times per condition -- "paired data"? It sounds that you wouldn't. But if we average over repetitions we obtain 20x2 data that is obviously "paired".

Comment: @amoeba No, only if the administration of condition A and condition B were designed in a balance exogenous contributors to variability would I consider the respective conditions "paired": there being of course 10 paired observations per participant each of which having perhaps a common subject-specific intercept. I did not understand that to be the design. To your 2nd point: I get confused on this terminology: e.g. people mistakenly(?) call pre/post data paired. There are 2 correlated observations within subject, but expected growth effects... are they paired merely because there are 2?

Comment: @AdamO. I think that my data is paired because "treatment" and "control" plots are constrained to the specific conditions in that particular "Location" (subject). Comparing treatments and controls without accounting for the internal (Local) variation makes none sense in my design and would introduce a lot of noise to the test. The only way I know to control that is taking location as the subject and samples from different treatments as paired/directly comparable data.

Comment: @Charly you're still not explaining this in a way I can understand. Are you saying the same subject serves as their own treatment and control? Like a surgery performed on one hand in an arthritic patient and the other left normal. Or did you random recruit two people from each site and assign them to treatment:control in a 1:1 fashion? Were these twins or siblings or... ?

Comment: @AdamO. Sorry, let me clarify the design. Inside the treatment plot(cropland), we have 10 sites (randomly chosen) where we sample insect abundance. In the control cropland we have another 10 sites where we do the same. We think that the sites between croplands (or the average of the 10 samples) can be treated as pairs since are subjected to the same location. That is repeated in 20 locations so we need to control for "location" when testing the effect of the treatment over the control. Thanks!